# How to print Ascending and Descending order any Number of table with for loop by user input value

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, conditional-statements

```js
function printTable() {
  var num;
  num = Number(document.getElementById("txtNumber").value);
  for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    var ascendingOdr = document.getElementById("ascendingOdr");
    ascendingOdr.innerHTML += num * i + "<br/>";

    var descendingOdr = document.getElementById("descendingOdr");
    descendingOdr.innerHTML += num * i + "<br/>";
  }
};
console.log(printTable())
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtNumber" placeholder="Enter number" /> <input type="button" value="Print Table." onclick="printTable()" />
<div style="display: flex;">
  <p id="ascendingOdr"></p>
  <p style="margin-left: 20px;" id="descendingOdr"></p>
</div>
```

For example print table of 5
i want print this ordering table with one for loop condition in Javascript
5
10
15
20
25
30
35
40
45
50

50
45
40
35
30
25
20
15
10
5

Comment: can you include html as well ([mcve])

Comment: <input type="text" id="txtNumber" placeholder="Enter number" />
        <input type="button" value="Print Table." onclick="printTable()" />
        <div style="display: flex;">
            <p id="ascendingOdr"></p>
            <p style="margin-left: 20px;" id="descendingOdr"></p>
        </div>

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get the descending order by building the inverse of the counter, i.e. if the loop goes to ten, you can do `num * (10 - i)`.

Here is a different solution that just uses a reversed copy of the ascending numbers:

```js
function printTable() {
  const num = Number(document.getElementById("txtNumber").value);
  const ascending = Array(10).fill(null).map((e,i) => (i+1) * num)
  const descending = [...ascending].reverse()
  document.getElementById("ascendingOdr").innerHTML = ascending.join('<br/>');
  document.getElementById("descendingOdr").innerHTML = descending.join('<br/>');
};
printTable()
```

```html
<input type="number" id="txtNumber" placeholder="Enter number" /> <input type="button" value="Print Table." onclick="printTable()" />
<div style="display: flex;">
  <p id="ascendingOdr"></p>
  <p style="margin-left: 20px;" id="descendingOdr"></p>
</div>
```